# Name of the notation $(s|z,u,n)$

Tags: notation, terminology, scientific-notation

what is the name of the notation , I didn't get it (as physics student we call $\langle q|p\rangle$ Braket notation) but in software books i am often seeing that notation how can you call it does it have a name $(s|z,u,n)$ those kind of things

i hope you understand my problem

Comment: I'm trying to understand your question: What is the problem with using the word "braket notation" or "bra-ket" notation?

Comment: problem not in bra-ket notation i don't understand other notation it uses paranthesis and pipe what does it do

Comment: Perhaps a particular example (with context) could be illuminating? I mean, please find a specific use case and then we can look at it together and think about what it means.

Comment: i find the answer it is called bayesian